# service-now configure ui action button with name service-now -I "Move to Next state"

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

service-now -I want to configure UI action with name Move to Next state so that i could change process flow with clicking on button "Move to next state"

Answer (score 0):

That's called a ui action. Documentation and examples here: https://developer.servicenow.com/blog.do?p=/post/training-ui-action-101/